# Not able to run Scriptcs scripts in Atom using atom-runner

Tags: atom-editor, scriptcs

I am trying to setup Atom editor on Mac for use with ScriptCs scripts. So I followed [the guide to do that](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Running-scripts-in-Atom).

```
execvp(): No such file or directory
```

I have scriptcs as an alias in my .profile. Running `scriptcs test.csx` in the terminal used to launch Atom, works. It seems like Atom is not aware of the profile alias.

What should I do to make this work in Atom ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom-runner is using a call to `exec` to invoke `scriptcs` directly, rather than going through a shell, so it won't be able to pick up anything that you have in your dotfiles. You'll either need to:

1. Put `scriptcs` on your `$PATH` normally, rather than using an alias. Sometimes you can do this with symlinks or changing its installation directory, for example.
2. Specify the absolute path to your `scriptcs` executable in your Atom config, instead:

```
'runner':
  'extensions':
    'csx': '/full/path/to/where/you/installed/scriptcs'
```